# Повтор игры Zerg Rush

Tags: svg, html, css, javascript

Если набрать в поиске Google слова Zerg Rush, то появятся выпадающий буквы O, которые понемногу будут разрушать весь текст поисковой выдачи. Если посмотреть исходники страницы, то видно

```
<div class="zr_zergling_container" style="-webkit-user-select: none; left: 390px; top: 720.5px; ">
    <div class="zr_yellow" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); "></div>
    <div class="zr_health" style="width: 20px; background-color: rgb(0, 153, 51); visibility: hidden; "></div>
</div>
```

Фоном элемента является картинка с буквой O. И где-то в скриптах идет манипулирование координатами и углом наклона элементов.

Есть желание повторить игру. Как проще всего это сделать?

1. Скопировать поход Google - div + js.
2. Рисовать все на HTML5 canvas (непонятно, что будет с остальным текстом страницы).
3. Использовать встроенный SVG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поворот идет только в восьми направлениях. Соответственно, CSS спрайты спасут мир от Canvas и SVG. Почему спасут? Потому что они тут совершенно не нужны.
Если нужен плавный поворот - однозначно канвас: SVG придется перепиливать еще, чтобы IE понял.